# NullPointerException on writing excel file with apache poi

Tags: java, apache-poi, poi-hssf, hssf

I am trying to load an excel file (xls) from template, set one cell's value and write it to another file. But i get this exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.FilteringDirectoryNode$FilteringIterator.<init>(FilteringDirectoryNode.java:193)
    at org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.FilteringDirectoryNode$FilteringIterator.<init>(FilteringDirectoryNode.java:188)
    at org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.FilteringDirectoryNode.getEntries(FilteringDirectoryNode.java:101)
    at org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.FilteringDirectoryNode.iterator(FilteringDirectoryNode.java:105)
    at org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.EntryUtils.copyNodes(EntryUtils.java:74)
    at org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.EntryUtils.copyNodes(EntryUtils.java:90)
    at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook.write(HSSFWorkbook.java:1395)
    at de.ajs.dailyreport.runtime.services.WorkDiaryExcel.write(WorkDiaryExcel.java:37)
    at de.ajs.dailyreport.runtime.services.WorkDiaryExcelTest.someTest(WorkDiaryExcelTest.java:35)
    ...
```

(by the way a really bad message ;-))

here is the code:

```
public class WorkDiaryExcel {

    private final Report report;

    /**
     * row, cell for date
     */
    private static final int[] DATE_FIELD = new int[] { 7, 7 };
    private HSSFWorkbook excel;

    public WorkDiaryExcel(Report report) {
        this.report = report;
        try(HSSFWorkbook excel = new HSSFWorkbook(WorkDiaryExcel.class.getResourceAsStream("/template.xls"))) {
            this.excel = excel;
            HSSFSheet sheet = excel.getSheetAt(0);
            sheet.getRow(DATE_FIELD[0]).getCell(DATE_FIELD[1]).setCellValue(report.getDate());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Problem on loading excel from template: ", e);
        }

    }

    public void write(OutputStream out){
        try {
            excel.write(out);
            out.flush();
            out.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Problem on writing excel to output stream: ", e);
        }
    }

}
```

This code is called from test:

```
@Test
public void someTest() throws IOException {
    WorkDiaryExcel to = new WorkDiaryExcel(reportMock);
    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("out.xls");
    to.write(out);
}
```

So what could cause the problem?

Comment: What version of Apache POI are you using? And if it isn't the most recent, what happens when you upgrade?

Comment: What does your reportMock return when getDate() is called?

Comment: Go to FilteringDirectoryNode.java:193 (you need source code of your POI version) and probably you'll find useful information

Comment: If you can reproduce it with the latest version and can produce a standalone unit test (including the valid Excel sample file), then please report a bug at Apache POI as it sounds like something is not handled correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem: I left the template open in excel. So as soon as i closed excel with the template file all worked fine - very odd isn't it?

Comment: I got the same problem, but I closed all the opened workbooks and files, but still getting null pointer exception while doing 'workBook.write(fileOut);'

Comment: i would double check if there is still an filehandle on the file (probably not excel but anything else). For this purpose i use "ProcessExplorer". Find->Find Handle or DLL